# Where Does Generated Connection String Come From?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Legacy system using Linq to SQL.  The following code gets generated for L2S:

```
public MyDataContext() : 
        base("Data Source=mydevserver;Initial Catalog=mycatalogue;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActive" +
                "ResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework", mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

We don't use this constructor, as we want to pass the connection string from a config file based on environment.  That said, we recently had a problem where a developer called the default constructor, resulting in us consuming development data in production.

Where does the connection string that gets generated in the default constructor come from?  Does it come from the app.config, i.e. the same connection string used for making updates to the model?

Is there any out-of-the-box way of having L2S **not** generate this constructor?

Comment: yes it comes from `app.config` or `web.config` depending it's web or desktop application

Comment: I believe it's copied from the connection string that appears Visual Studio's Server Explorer. (the same value also gets copied into the `.config` file)

Comment: if the default constructor call was consuming development data in production then that database Datasource was hard coded .. sounds like that can be fixed if you change it to point to Production table update the appropriate .Config file.. also check the settings.Settings to make sure they didn't add entries there as well